# Android Theme all ALL API

Tags: android, title

I have a problem with Android theme. 
It shows me Title bar and i really dont want it.
The problem is that i dont have it in 2.3.3 and have it in Kit Kat.
I tried this:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
```

Manifest

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: I don't understand the code you posted. Did you put style tags in your manifest? They don't belong there.

Comment: Yes. It is a piece of Manifest <application... And the first is from style. It works fine but Title bar always appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this style for your `Activity`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

But if you want to support anything down to 2.3.3 you have to put that style in the style.xml in the values-v13 resource folder. If it doesn't exist, just create it.

Comment: Works good. Have just another question: if i want to set different themes i could use there folders with defferent API levels?

Comment: Yes, there are also many other resource selectors. That's how you also create a different layout for bigger screens like tablets. But they should be used for backwards compatibility only. Not to set a different appearance for your app on different api levels. You are after all trying to create a unified experience across all api levels.